# ActiveMQ Interceptors to Filter Queues

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm currently trying to show the logged in user of the web console the destinations (queues and topics) that belong only to him.

I don't want a User to see queues that he's not authorized to see.

Can this functionality be done using ActiveMQ interceptors?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The Web Console uses JMX to list and manage queues. It won't be affected by interceptors.

If you want such things in the Web Console, consider rewrite the console to take user authorization into account when listing queues. It's not a quick fix but could probably be done if you manage to read the authorizations from AMQ somehow.